# Problems with Getting NSTimer to invoke method

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I'm just learning to use Objective-C and have tried to use the `NSTimer` with scheduledTime Interval with no luck.  The code I'm using looks as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "timerNumber1.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {

    NSTimer *timerNumber1;

    NSInteger counter=0;

    while (counter<5){


        timerNumber1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:timerNumber1 selector: @selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        counter++;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

timerNumber1 header looks as follows

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface timerNumber1 : NSObject
-(void) updateTimer;

@end
```

and implementation is

```
#import "timerNumber1.h"

@implementation timerNumber1

-(void) updateTimer{
NSLog(@"Timer Updated!");

}
@end
```

The method never seems to fire and I never see Timer Updated.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `timerNumber1` is not initialized yet (probably `nil`), so the `target` parameter is not going to be valid. The `updateTimer` method will be called on the `nil` object, which fails silently in Objective-C.

You need to create the object first, then you can proceed as you have done.

Sidenote: It's a bit unusual that you have a class with the exact same name as your variable. That's usually not a good idea, at least for readability's sake. Also, I'm not 100 % sure you need to create one timer for every time you want it to repeat, since you have `repeats:YES`. But I'll let you be the judge of what you want to do with your code. :-)

Edit: Just noticed something else too, the selector might be a bit off -- there is a `:` in the selector, but `updateTimer` does not take any parameters. I don't think there should be a colon there in that case.

So, try something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSTimer *timer;
        timerNumber1 *timerNumber1Object = [[timerNumber1 alloc] init];

        NSInteger counter=0;

        while (counter<5){
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:timerNumber1Object selector: @selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be really nice if people would post a comment with the reason for their down-vote so that people who post answers can improve themselves. A little something called *constructive criticism*. :-|

Comment: The reason for the while loop was to allow the timer to run.  I think however I need to be in a runLoop.  I tried removing the while loop and in the header I used NSTimer rather than NSObject.  However I still get the same results.